# Iterator of `char32_t` from an UTF-8 file

Tags: c++, utf-8, c++20, iostream

Suppose I have an `std::ifstream` open on an UTF-8 encoded file. Is there a way to obtain an iterator over corresponding UTF-32 characters as `char32_t`?

Something like:

```
for(char32_t char : as_utf32(stream)) {
  // something...
}
```

I've found a lot of ways to convert strings but I'd rather avoid to read the file in memory and decoding it all at once.

Is there a way to do this with the standard library?

Comment: UTF-32 is not "decoded". It is still an encoding of Unicode into bytes.

Comment: Take a look at `std::wifstream`.

Comment: This is what the `read` function of a stream if for.  It allows you to read an arbitrary number of bytes from the file and place them into an object.

Comment: `read()` reads `char` buffers, I need `char32_t`, which is not like reading 4 bytes at the time: the file is encoded in UTF-8, so data has to be decoded first.

Comment: @Botje as far as I know, `std::wifstream` reads `wchar_t`, whose encoding is dependent on the platform. I need UTF-32 encoded `char32_t`

Comment: @gigabytes In that case you're going to want a library.  You might be able to coble something together without one, but C++ doesn't really do Unicode.  It just was updated with types to support it, it still needs the library to get fleshed out.

Comment: @NathanOliver But what is `std::codecvt_utf8` for? As far as I know, it can be used to decode UTF-8 into UTF-32 *strings*, I just need the same thing for streams.

Comment: `std::codecvt_utf8` was deprecated in C++17 and will some day be removed.

Comment: There's a way to do everything in C++, you just have to do it yourself. In this case it's implementing your own iterator that reads from the underlying `std::ifstream` and converting it to `char32_t`. There's nothing in the C++ library that does this, but you simply need to write this code yourself.